# failed to execute first example of Differential Algebraic Equations

Tags: julia, differentialequations.jl

I am using JuliaPro v0.6.0.1 and the JunoIDE
I tried to apply the DifferentialEquations.jl. In order to run a first example I added the package DifferentialEquations followed by the using statement. In a next step I copied the first example:

```
f(t,u) = 1.01*u
u0=1/2
tspan = (0.0,1.0)
prob = ODEProblem(f,u0,tspan)
sol = solve(prob,Tsit5(),reltol=1e-8,abstol=1e-8)
using Plots
plot(sol,linewidth=5,title="Solution to the linear ODE with a thick line",
 xaxis="Time (t)",yaxis="u(t) (in μm)",label="My Thick Line!") #    legend=false
plot!(sol.t, t->0.5*exp(1.01t),lw=3,ls=:dash,label="True Solution!")
```

Instead of getting the expected graphic I've got the message:

```
UndefVarError: ODEProblem not defined
```

Furthermore I've got the warnings right after the: *using DifferentialEquations* statement

```
WARNING: The call to compilecache failed to create a usable precompiled cache file for module StochasticDiffEq. Got:
WARNING: Module Iterators uuid did not match cache file.
> LoadError: Declaring __precompile__(true) is only allowed in module files being imported.
```

which I do not understand. Nevertheless the last warning deals with StochasticDiffEq whereas I'm applying an Ordinary Differential Equation problem.

Any help is appropiated

Comment: JuliaPro is incompatible with some packages including DifferentialEquations. I would avoid using JuliaPro and instead use a standard installation until JuliaPro is updated.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I am just begginer and I think that Julia has very big potential. But it also seems to me that it has some issues with backward compatibility. And these are very important to resolve before v1.0

Comment: Yes, but there's nothing I can do about this. [Iterators.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/Iterators.jl) broke because an Iterators module was added to Julia's Base in v0.6 (see the deprecation warning). The solution here is to add `using Iterators` to the top of every file to avoid the naming error, but in reality this is just a hard version incompatibility which will still have other errors. The next version of JuliaPro has this all fixed and should be out next week, and DiffEq has mostly stabilized so that the breaking changes will likely be due to breaking Julia 1.0 changes.

Comment: @ChrisRackaucka Thanks for your input. For the next few days I'll stay with  JuliaPro v0.6.0.1 and wait for the following version of JuliaPro.
Carsten

Comment: @ChrisRackaucka Thanks for your input. For the next few days I'll stay with  JuliaPro v0.6.0.1 and wait for the following version of JuliaPro.
Carsten

Comment: @Liso What is really convincing is the speed of Julia. In my case I developed RCWA algorithm in which  eigen-equations must be solved including large matrices. I found Julia is at least 10 times faster compared to e.g. Matlab (depending on the method) applying not optimized program code.
Carsten

Answer (score 0):

JuliaPro is incompatible with some packages including DifferentialEquations. I would avoid using JuliaPro and instead use a standard installation until JuliaPro is updated.